# Why is google analytics data not being collected for my android Flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, google-analytics

I have released the android app and the iOS app of my Flutter project. In my project, I have used  **firebase_messaging** and **firebase_remote_config** libraries and both of these features are properly working in both android and iOS app. Google Analytics is enabled in the Firebase project. From the analytics dashboard, it is seen that the analytics data (e.g. daily active users, first_open event etc) are automatically being collected for the iOS app, but not for the android app.

I have properly followed Steps 1-3 mentioned [here in the official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android). However, in the dashboard I am getting the following for android.

[image]

What point am I missing in android project setup? Is this related to SHA certificate fingerprint? Currently, I have only SHA-1 added.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Add https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics to your app. It will provide steps to add it to the Android app as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding **firebase_core** ([Step 4 here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android)) solved the problem. Since it was not required for iOS, I had skipped it, only later to find it mandatory for Android. Now analytics data is automatically being collected for both android and ios app.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem after my previous flutter update, it used to work even without firebase_core nor firebase_analytic plugin. I added the 2 plugins and the problem still persists. Can you please share what version of flutter, firebase_core and firebase_analytic you're using?

Comment: @Zane My flutter version is  1.22.2, firebase_core and firebase analytics versions as used in pubspec.yaml file are ^0.4.0+9 and ^5.0.2 respectively.

Comment: Im facing with the same problem and as I understand you solved your problem and i want to ask you, adding firebase_core and firebase_analytics to your pubspec.yaml is it enough for solving problem or should i do something else too after adding firebase_core and firebase_analytics to pubspec.yaml. Because in some solving examples they are adding some codes to their main codes for tracking different datas but i dont want to use code for track specific datas, i want to track or collect datas automatically without adding any code

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include an SHA certificate in production. This is optional, just for testing.

Did you follow the documentation correctly? Please double check in case you missed a step.

Please make sure that you add a firebase analystics observer into page navigations. For just to test it, as per the documentation:

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics

```
MaterialApp(
  home: MyAppHome(),
  navigatorObservers: [
    FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: FirebaseAnalytics()),
  ],
);
```

Comment: I do not need to track the page navigations, just need the data that Firebase tracks automatically when Firebase sdk is setup in the project. Without the navigator observer code, data is currently being tracked in iOS but not in android. So I am guessing thta there is a way to have it without adding the navigator observer, that i wanted to know.

Comment: if you are not including navigation observers, and there is no code where you invoke firebase events, then nothing can get sent. You will need to manually write up events for android, based on the business logic you are calling. For example, you can create a firebase event that tracks when users make in app purchases, then send the information to firebase analytics as the event "card_purchase"

Comment: here's a good article to get you started: https://medium.com/flutterdevs/firebase-analytics-2044e865efc4