# Firebase Analytics for Flutter not recording data

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am trying to add Firebase Analytics to my Flutter WebApp, and followed the official documentation and tutorials to configure the service, however every time I look at the the Firebase Analytics dashboard, the chart shows 0 users.

I'm not looking to log any custom or specific events, for the time being, I just want to view basic metrics like daily active users, unique users, etc., which, from my understanding, is automatically configured once you go through the setup and initialize it in your app. Even then, it's still not working.

Here are the steps that I've done for setup:

- Install the firebase CLI and login, according to the steps listed here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#mac-linux-auto-script
- Install and configure flutterfire following the steps https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web
- Initialize Firebase and Analytics with the following code:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.dart';

late FirebaseAnalytics analytics;

/// Entry point into webapp
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I know this isn't much to go on, just looking at the code, I'm not understanding why this is sufficient to start Analytics tracking, but that's what had been mentioned in some of the YouTube tutorials I had watched on this. What else am I missing?

Comment: Does it log event in analytics debugview?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is google analytics data not being collected for my android Flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65996309/why-is-google-analytics-data-not-being-collected-for-my-android-flutter-app)